# How to get the ref which is in a child component in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to access a ref from a parent component which is defined in the child component. I've got a file where I call the parent component and inside of the component I call 2 child components like so:

```
<my-component>
    <component-header></component-header>
    <component-content></component-content>
</my-component>
```

Inside `my-component` I've got a `<slot></slot>` and no other html, but that is where I need to call a ref which is listed in the `component-header`. Here is my `component-header` file:

```
<template>
  <div ref="mycomponentHeader">
    <slot>
      // Here some other html
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

How will I be able to call the `mycomponentHeader` ref inside the `my-component` parent? I've tried calling the ref like this:

```
      console.log(this.$parent.$refs.mycomponentHeader)
      console.log(this.$refs.mycomponentHeader)
      console.log(this.$refs)
      console.log(this.$children.$refs.mycomponentHeader)
```

But these resulted in an undefined, an empty object and a cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$refs'). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't. component-header should have a ref if you want to access the instance. A child should provide public api if you want to manipulate it. This is most likely XY problem. Consider reasking about what you want to achieve instead of addressing potentially wrong solution.

Comment: Okay thank you. What I'm trying to do is to manipulate the dom. I've now set the ref where I call the `component-header` and tried accessing it by doing: `this.$parent.$refs.mycomponentHeader` I do get a response now. Thank you for your help @EstusFlask

Comment: You generally shouldn't manipulate DOM directly in Vue, it's not idiomatic and can lead to problems. And even when you should, a comp should have public method or prop for that. What you're currently doing is possible but is universally a bad practice, including the use of $parent.

Comment: I'm sorry for not providing the full code on this problem, but I'm making use of props in the child components. The purpose of this vue package is to keep it simple to implement and also really flexable for the non FE developer. @EstusFlask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply achieve that by assigning a `ref` into a child component element and then access the child component inner `ref` variable from the parent component.

In parent component template **:**

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component ref="childComponent"/>
<parent-component>
```

In script **:**

```
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$refs.childComponent) // Here you can access any properties or methods of a child component.
}
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['childmsg'],
  template: '<div ref="mycomponentHeader">{{ childmsg }}</div>',
  methods: {
    getChildRef() {
        return this.$refs.mycomponentHeader;
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.childComponent.getChildRef().textContent)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child ref="childComponent" childmsg="This is a child message">
  </child>
</div>
```

Comment: For me this results in an undefined error, but because I didn't specify that the parent component is called within a blade file (because it's a vue package which I'm creating) I'll accept this answer. It could be helpful for others!

Answer (score 3):

```
<my-component>
    <component-header ref="header"></component-header>
    <component-content></component-content>
</my-component>



mounted(){
  this.$refs.header.$refs.mycomponentHeader
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Sorry I didn't specify that the vue child components aren't called in the parent vue file. It's actually a seperate blade file which calls the parent component which uses a `<slot>` to then call the child components.